# How to get the closest the column value by the bin Multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (`df_value_bin`) with Multiindex which is the binned values, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'value'])

a_bins = np.arange(-3, 4, 1)
b_bins = np.arange(-2, 4, 2)

df['a_bins'] = pd.cut(df['a'], bins=a_bins)
df['b_bins'] = pd.cut(df['b'], bins=b_bins)
df_value_bin = df.groupby(['a_bins','b_bins']).agg({'value':'mean'})
```

Here's the quickview of `df_value_bin`:

```
                     value
a_bins   b_bins           
(-3, -2] (-2, 0] -0.417606
         (0, 2]  -0.267035
(-2, -1] (-2, 0] -0.296727
         (0, 2]  -0.112280
(-1, 0]  (-2, 0]  0.459780
         (0, 2]   0.131588
(0, 1]   (-2, 0]  0.110268
         (0, 2]   0.287755
(1, 2]   (-2, 0]  0.254337
         (0, 2]  -0.627460
(2, 3]   (-2, 0] -0.075165
         (0, 2]  -0.589709
```

Then, I want to get the closest `value` of `df_value_bin` when giving some `a` and `b`.

Let's say a=1.5 and b=-1, then we should get value=0.254337.

### Attempt 1

I can generate the boolean mask for `a_bins` and `b_bins`:

```
a_test = 1.5
b_test = -1

boolean_a = df_value_bin.index.get_level_values('a_bins').categories.contains(a_test)
boolean_b = df_value_bin.index.get_level_values('b_bins').categories.contains(b_test)

print(boolean_a, boolean_b) # Output: [False False False False  True False] [ True False]
```

However, I have no idea of using the masks to select the row ...

### Attempt 2

I can get the index directly:

```
index_a = np.digitize(a_test, a_bins, right=True)
index_b = np.digitize(b_test, b_bins, right=True)

print(index_a, index_b) # Output: 5 1
```

Again, I don't know how to use the index to select the row directly.

### Notes

It seems the second method should be quicker as it uses `np.digitize()`.
If you have any idea to complete it or other better methods, please feel free to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just index with numbers in this case:

```
df_value_bin.loc[(1.5, -1)]
```

Output (ignore value, which is generated randomly, look at the `Name`):

```
value    0.047439
Name: ((1, 2], (-2, 0]), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent method! In case someone needs the input of array, here's the method: `test = np.array([-1.5, 0, 1]); df_value_bin.loc[zip(test, test)]`

Comment: If users prefer using labels, then `df_value_bin.xs((1.5, -1), level=['a_bins', 'b_bins'])` meet it.